# SQL - GROUPING, ID, NAME

Tags: sql

I was wondering what the answer should be for 1c. on this website:

http://sqlzoo.net/6.htm

```
SELECT company 
FROM route WHERE stop=4
GROUP BY name, ID
```

this obviously isn't working, the ID and name isn't showing up no matter what. What is missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT stops.id, stops.name
FROM route 
INNER JOIN stops on route.stop = stops.id
WHERE route.num = 4 AND route.company = 'LRT'
```

You need to join the tables as the data you want to return is in a different table to the one which filters the data.

Answer (score 1):

This works and does not include any unnecessary table joins. A good rule of thumb is to use `EXISTS` to verify values in a table that you do not need the output for. Otherwise, you would use a `JOIN`

```
SELECT stops.id, stops.name
FROM stops
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM route 
    WHERE route.stop = stops.id AND num = '4' AND company = 'LRT'
)
```

Comment: why use EXISTS instead a JOIN?

Comment: @wickedrunr http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx
       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177346/can-an-inner-join-offer-better-performance-than-exists   It depends on the query, like these articles say, but generally, if you are not using the output I have found EXISTS to be more performant

Answer (score 0):

It gives you this error:

> sql: Unknown column 'name' in 'group statement'

There is no `name` in `route` tabel. 
The tables structure are:

```
stops(id, name)
route(num,company,pos, stop)
```

So the answer for this quiz is:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
FROM   route r, stops s 
WHERE  r.stop= s.id 
and    r.num = 4 AND r.company = 'LRT'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.id, s.name
from stops s
inner join route r
    on s.id = r.stop
where r.num= 4
    AND r.company= 'LRT'
```