# Return only one value of Table A where exists in Table B

Tags: sql, db2

Find unique records in table A where exist in table B.

Table A

```
CustID, name, addr1
A001, Bill Adams, 123 main st
B007, Jon Brown, 229 oak st
C029, Sue Cook, 16 park ave
```

Table B

```
CustID, invoice_no
A001, 189
A001, 202
A001, 243
C029, 212
```

Desired results: only 1 instance of A001 from table B and not 3:

```
A001, Bill Adams
C029, Sue Cook
```

current sql:

```
select A.CustID, A.name
from table A
join table B on A.custID = B.custID
```

Comment: Simply add `DISTINCT` to your Select or switch to `EXISTS`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT A.CustID, A.Name, A.Addr1
FROM Table A
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CustID From Table) B ON A.CustID = B.CustID
```

You could also do WHERE EXISTS instead of a JOIN but my understanding is the JOIN will have better performance.

Comment: Performance will vary depending on the size of B table and the cost of the DISTINCT. Personally I prefer to use EXISTS since it is much easier to read (it does precisely what it says it does!) Also, more on the question of performance here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177346/can-an-inner-join-offer-better-performance-than-exists

Answer (score 1):

The duplicates happen because of the join which is similar to a cartesian product.

If you go with something like this it should work :

```
SELECT A.CustID, A.name
FROM table A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE A.custID= B.custID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply adding

```
select distinct A.custID, A.name
```

as @dnoeth suggested unless there are issues with this approach.  Seems to do the trick for me.

Comment: Should work fine until you need to add additional columns or joins. If that never happens... no problem!

Answer (score 0):

solution 1

```
select * from tableA f1
inner join lateral
(
 select * from TableB f2
 where f1.CustID=f2.CustID
 fetch first rows only
) f3 on 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 :

```
select distinct f1.* 
from tableA f1
inner join TableB f2 on f1.CustID=f2.CustID
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 3 :

```
select * from tableA f1
where f1.CustID in ( select f2.CustID  from TableB f2)
```